# node.js mySQL connection via a singleton

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I'm using a singleton pattern for mySQL  connections in node.js, there's one and only one connection for the whole application to use, my concern is if there's some timeout setting for this connection held by the singleton.

This connection is supposed to live throughout the life cycle of the app. I searched and found some persistence examples using pool but not sure if this applies to this example, there's no pool of connections, there's only one connection to be shared between the components, the question is, is there some timeout setting that will kill the connection after it's held for long?

```
puremvc.define(
{
name: "common.model.connections.App",

constructor: function() { 
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: common.Config.mySQLHost,
        user: common.Config.mySQLUsername,
        password: common.Config.mySQLPassword,
        database: common.Config.mySQLDatabase
    });

    this.connection.connect();
 }
    },
{
}, 
{
NAME: "App",
instance: null,
connection: null,

getInstance: function() {
    if(common.model.connections.App.instance == null) {
        common.model.connections.App.instance = new common.model.connections.Fico();
    }
    return common.model.connections.App.instance;
},

getConnection: function() {
    return common.model.connections.App.getInstance().connection;
}
}
);
```

Comment: this is actually a mysql concern and not node.js, try to use the property http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout to increase the time to keep the connection opened

Comment: @fmodos thanks for your comment, it seems like there's a limited life of a connection, 31536000 (2147483 on windows) seconds for inactive connections, is there a way to set timeout to unlimited?

Comment: no, but it wouldnt be a good approach to keep an unlimited opened connection to the BD.

Comment: Ok, so what would be a good approach while employing the singleton pattern

Comment: check if the connection is closed and then open it, before return the connection in the function getConnection. You can use the singleton to store the connection object instance, but it doesn't mean that the object will always have the connection opened.

Comment: Ok, can you please answer that using some code for the close checking, I'm new to node.js. I think the place to check would be in the getInstance method

Comment: the getconnection is teh right place, I will edit my answer with this couple in a couple hours... kind a busy right now

Comment: I improved my answer with the code example for the singleton.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is actually a MySQL concern and not Node.js. You can use the property `wait_timeout` of the MySQL to increase the number of time to keep the connection opened.

Check more details about this property [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Below is a code example for your singleton that will create a new connection when the current one is closed. In the scenario, you will never have more than 1 connection active if you always use the App Singleton to get the connection:

```
getConnection: function() {
    var app = common.model.connections.App.getInstance();
    if(!app.connection.isConnected()){
       //connect if connection is closed.
       app.connection.connect();
    }
    return app.connection;
}
```