# node.js using express-hbs to rendreing rows on webpage

Tags: html, node.js

I working on a code to printing some user info on a webpage using node.js and express-hbs

I tried this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Person List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {{#each person}}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{person.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td><a href='/person/'+person.id>{{person.firstname}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{person.GameId}}</td>
                </tr> 

         {{/each}}
    </table>
<td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
</body>
</html>
```

node.js code

```
app.get('/usersrooms', function (req, res, next) {

        var personList = [];
    //var userslist = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";    
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({"status_code": 500,"status_message": "internal server error"});
        } else {
            // Loop check on each row
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                // Create an object to save current row's data
                var person = {
                    'email':rows[i].email,
                    'firstname':rows[i].firstname,
                    'GameId':rows[i].GameId,
                    'id':rows[i].id
                }
                // Add object into array
                personList.push(person);
        }

        res.render('index', {"personList": personList});
        }
    });

    // Close the MySQL connection
connection.end();

});
```

> but I get this error when I run it and the server disconnect and I don't get any data on my webpage
>
> ```
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
> ```
>
> Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the call to `connection.end();`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20693128/459233) which explains why **`connection.end()` should be called only when the application is being shut down**

Regarding the lack of rows in HTML, it is probably because while you send the list of persons to the template in the `personList` param, you're iterating over an array called `person` in it. Try with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Person List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {{#each personList}}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{id}}
                    </td>
                    <td><a href='/person/{{id}}'>{{firstname}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{GameId}}</td>
                </tr> 

         {{/each}}
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I deleted the `<td>{{person.firstname}}</td>` part, because it is not obvious to me whose person you want to display the `firstname` there

Comment: thanks but why i can't get any data from my database inside my table ? i just get white page

Comment: done, I've updated the answer to address your second concern

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/usersrooms', function (req, res, next) {
    var personList = [];
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ "status_code": 500, "status_message": "internal server error" });
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
            //return here to prevent second res call
            return;
        } else {
            // Loop check on each row
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                // Create an object to save current row's data
                var person = {
                    'email': rows[i].email,
                    'firstname': rows[i].firstname,
                    'GameId': rows[i].GameId,
                    'id': rows[i].id
                }
                // Add object into array
                personList.push(person);
            }

            res.render('index', { "personList": personList });
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I've revised the answer to remove the call to `connection.end()`  You likely are getting an error in your query - I added a console log to print the error.  run your code in a debugger to see what's actually happening.