# does the nextjs api honor promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, backend

I hope you are well, I have a problem, I am learning NEXTJS and working with its api, and it turns out that when I click very fast the promises get bugged. Or something similar, I leave the tests in this short video of 30s and a demonstration of the code, I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/K0JTMxpFLQs

------------ CODE ----------

MY REQUEST AXIOS:

```
axios.post("/api/reaction", data).then((response) => { return response.data }).then(response => {
        if (response.react) {
            setNew[key].youLike = true
            setNew[key].likes = response.likes
            setting(setNew => [...setNew])
        } else {
            setNew[key].youLike = false
            setNew[key].likes = response.likes
            setting(setNew => [...setNew])
        }
    })
```

My backend:

```
export default async function react(req, res) {
let msg, msg_type, react, likes
let { type, id } = req.body
let myId = mySession(req)

if (myId && type && id) {
    react = await youLike(myId, id, type)

    console.log(react)
    if (react) {
        await executeQuery({ query: `DELETE FROM cms_likes WHERE owner_id='${myId}' and type='${type}' and post_id='${id}'` })
        await executeQuery({ query: `UPDATE cms_posts SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id='${id}' ` })
        react = false
    } else {
        await executeQuery({ query: `INSERT INTO cms_likes (owner_id,type,post_id,time) VALUES ('${myId}','${type}','${id}','${timeNow("s")}') ` })
        await executeQuery({ query: `UPDATE cms_posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='${id}' ` })
        react = true
    }

    likes = await executeQuery({ query: `SELECT likes FROM cms_posts WHERE id='${id}'` })
} else {
    msg_type = "error"
    msg = "!Opps error al enviar tu peticion"
}


res.send({ msg, msg_type, react, likes: likes[0]?.likes })
```

}

By clicking the button many times, the like button doesn't do the promise to check if it exists or not very well, and doubles the likes.

EXISTS SLOW CLIC

[slowclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZVJl.png)

response:

> 0 no found
> 1 Yes there are
> 0 no found
> 1 Yes there are
> 0 no found

FAST CLIC RESPONSE:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn2P6.png)

2 DUPLICATE
2 DUPLICATE
0 no found
1 Yes there are
0 no found
1 Yes there are
0 no found
3 duplicate

Understand how promises work well, in order to find a solution to this problem, and my post will help people who may have the same error.

My connection SQL and FUNCTION EXECUTEQUERY

```
const db = mysql({
config: {
    host: "localhost",
    database: "baalbcms",
    user: "root",
    password: ""
}
```

})

```
export default async function executeQuery({ query, values }) {
try {
    const results = await db.query(query, values)
    await db.end()
    return results
} catch (err) {
    return err;
}
```

}

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a video of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi Done, post improved, thanks and sorry.

Comment: This isn't really related to Next.js but race conditions in your SQL queries since they're not run in a transaction.

Comment: @AKX Update, my post, see the last code, do you see any error in those connection functions?, and thank you very much for giving me that answer friend!

Answer (score 1):

To make your SQL more robust, you should always count the actual number of likes based on the likes table; as it is, it's possible for those to get out of sync.

I also took the liberty of fixing the SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code by using `values`.

This would be better still if you ran the queries in a single transaction, but that can't be easily done with your current `db` [that you `end` after every query (which you shouldn't do)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692989/node-mysql-where-does-connection-end-go).

```
if (react) {
  await executeQuery({
    query: "DELETE FROM cms_likes WHERE owner_id=? and type=? and post_id=?",
    values: [myId, type, id],
  });
} else {
  await executeQuery({
    query: "INSERT INTO cms_likes (owner_id,type,post_id,time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    values: [myId, type, id, timeNow("s")],
  });
}
await executeQuery({
  query: "UPDATE cms_posts SET likes=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cms_likes WHERE type=? and post_id=?) WHERE id=?",
  values: [type, id, id],
});
likes = await executeQuery({ query: `SELECT likes FROM cms_posts WHERE id=?`, values: [id] });
```