# Break infinite loop in node repl?

Tags: node.js, terminal

Is there a way to break out of an infinite loop in the node.js REPL?

For example, running `while (true) {}` essentially hangs the REPL so intensely that no combination of `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-C` have any effect. The only thing I've found that works is to kill the node process or close the terminal window.

Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: There is not. The REPL is busy, so it doesn't read input (`Ctrl-D`) or handle interrupts (`Ctrl-C`). It needs to be killed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to kill the process, you can use a process manager for that or `Ctrl-C` on the terminal window.

[Quitting node.js gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958780/quitting-node-js-gracefully)