# Stopping Node.js gracefully

Tags: node.js, signals, exit, terminate

How to stop Node.js application gracefully?

I need to write my memory content into file, on receiving killing signals (e.g., `SIGINT` (2), `SIGTERM` (3)), before termination, so as to do a "graceful shutdown". How to do that?

PS. 
This is not the same question as [Quitting node.js gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958780/quitting-node-js-gracefully), as the question was wrong, doing `ctrl+z` instead of `ctrl+c`, and the answer doesn't cover handling killing signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen to `exit` or `SIGINT` using

```
process.on("exit", () => /* this will be called on the exit event */);


process.on("SIGINT", () => /* this will be called on the SIGINT event */);
```