# How can i shut down the nodejs server by force?

Tags: node.js

Hello i am using goorm ide(clouding service)
n i've got some problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcIUq.png)

As you can see, despite of closed the server, it is being working
Is there anyone who know how to shut down the nodejs server process by force in terminal in goorm IDE?

Comment: press ctrl+c to shut the server down

Comment: i did already, but it's still running

Comment: go to the terminal and press ctrl+c it has to work

Comment: You can find your answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958964/10967697