# node.js http server takes long time to close

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs http server. After sending one request and getting the response back I'm trying to close it using server.close() but it takes a very long time to close (more than 60s).
What can be the problem?

**Edit**

Currently I'm using chromes advanced rest client for testing, sending one request results with the slow closing after getting the response, as far as I know it should not stuck with keep-alive.
I'm definitely closing my response with response.end() after response.write().

Here is some code:

```
handleRequest = function(request, response) {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() {
        // get some data from db...
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.write(result);
        response.end();
    });
});

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8000);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    if (server != undefined) {
        console.log("Closing Server...");
        server.close(function (e) {
            if (e) {
                throw 'Error on closing server';
            } else {
                console.log("Server closed");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Stuck with keep-alive connections? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5263716/139010

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had included some sample code. Are you sure you are ending your responses?

Comment: I think you left out what might be causing the problem: *"get some data from db..."*

Comment: I found out the response returns with keep-alive, although I'm not setting it anywhere, what may be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

please check that you have close your response, after sending your data.

**response.end()**

If this doesn't work you can post you code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the server process that you want to terminate, you should try `process.exit('SIGINT');` or `process.exit()` right after your `response.end()`.
This will end you server and the execution of your script.

Note that all exit signals excepted for `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` can be intercepted by the process.

`server.close()` only stops the server from accepting new connections and closes all connections connected to this server `which are not sending a request` or waiting for a response.